# Does Completed workflow instances automatically cleaned up after 30 days in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

We have one sharepoint 2013 declarative workflow associated on one list. Now If I goes to workflow details page of any list item which is more than **30 days** ago, Then no any running/completed workflows are there.

I googled about it & found that sharepoint timer job will delete workflow association after **60 days** of completion. But in our environment we cant able to see completed workflow instances after 30 days.

Does Completed workflow instances automatically cleaned up after 30 days in sharepoint 2013 ???

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

By default it is 60 days but one can change that retention to different numbers.

- Check If There is any information policy / retention policy applied on that list.which can delete the items from list.
- Also check if someone manually change the retention from 60 days to 30...you can get the idea from this link https://psconfig.com/post/41929400862/setting-autocleanupdays-with-powershell-in
- Lastly Check If items are moving into another list after 30 days.

Comment: Thanks waqas sarwar. Now  I am trying to get current value of  "AutoCleaupDays" property of workflow association but I'm facing problem. Can you please help me? Here is detailed question.  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/232469/how-to-get-autocleanupdays-property-of-workflow-in-sharepoint-2013

Answer (score 0):

try the following to set the AutoCleanupDays for all workflow associations on a list.

```
# Sample Usage 
# Set-SPListWorkflowAssocationCleanup -WebUrl "http://intranet" -ListName "Shared Documents" -CleanupDays 365 -ReportOnly:$false 


function Set-SPListWorkflowAssocationCleanup { 
    param ( 
        [string] $WebUrl = $(Read-Host -prompt "Enter a Url"), 
        [string] $ListName = $(Read-Host -prompt "Enter a List Name"), 
        [int32] $CleanupDays = $(Read-Host -prompt "Enter the number of Cleanup Days"), 
        [switch] $ReportOnly = $true 
         )         

     $web = Get-SPWeb $WebUrl; 
     if ($web -eq $null) { 
         Write-Error -message "Error: Web Not Found" -category InvalidArgument 
     } else { 
         $list = $web.Lists[$ListName]; 
         if ($list -eq $null) { 
             Write-Error -message "Error: List Not Found" -category InvalidArgument 
         } else { 
             [Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowAssociation[]] $wfaMods = @(); 
             foreach ($wfa in $list.WorkflowAssociations) { 
                 $message = "Found Workflow Association for " + $wfa.Name + " with AutoCleanupDays set to " + $wfa.AutoCleanupDays 
                 Write-Verbose -message $message -verbose 

                 if ($ReportOnly -eq $false) { 
                     $wfa.AutoCleanupDays = $CleanupDays; 
                     $wfaMods = $wfaMods + $wfa; 
                 } 
             } 

             if ($ReportOnly -eq $false) { 
                 foreach ($wfa in $wfaMods) { 
                     $message = "Setting AutoCleanupDays for " + $wfa.Name + " to " + $CleanupDays 
                     Write-Verbose -message $message -verbose 
                     $list.WorkflowAssociations.Update($wfa); 
                 } 
             } 
         } 
     } 
 }
```