# How to get "AutoCleanupDays" property of workflow in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow

I'm trying to get "`AutoCleaupDays`" property of workflow association but `workflowassociation` always returning null. Then I tried with `workflowSubscriptionService` & here I am getting my workflow but it does not expose "AutoCleaupDays" property. below is my code

**CODE 1: Using SPList.WorkflowAssociations**

```
SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("IT-Request-Form");
SPWorkflowAssociationCollection WAC = list.WorkflowAssociations;//Its returing null
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culinfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us");
SPWorkflowAssociation WA = WAC.GetAssociationByName("WorkflowAssociation_5fb922d2693c4b718c652ce7d5eb49ce", culinfo);
int days = WA.AutoCleanupDays;
```

*SPWorkflowAssociationCollection  returning null.*

**CODE 2: Using GetWorkflowSubscriptionService**

```
var workflowServiceManager = new WorkflowServicesManager(web);
var workflowSubscriptionService = workflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService();
var subscriptions = workflowSubscriptionService.EnumerateSubscriptionsByList(list.ID);
foreach (var workflowSubscription in subscriptions)
{
 //here i get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception
 string autoCleanupDays = workflowSubscription.GetProperty("AutoCleanupDays").ToString();

 //Then i checked Properties & allProperties does not contains "AutoCleanupDays" Property
 ICollection<string> allProperties  = workflowSubscription.PropertyDefinitions.Keys;

}
```

So how I get "AutoCleaupDays" value of workflow in **SP2013**?

Answer (score 0):

I replied your post:
[Does Completed workflow instances automatically cleaned up after 30 days in sharepoint 2013?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/232411/does-completed-workflow-instances-automatically-cleaned-up-after-30-days-in-shar/232495#232495)

I provided how to set AutoCleanupDays property using PowerShell.